# change the enddate choice with jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, textbox, datepicker, range

I have 2 textboxes: StartDate and endDate
How can I make so the user will be able to pick from the endDate only the dates starting from the startDate text box and ending 24 hours after the startDate?

I tried this but it didnt work:

```
$("#startDate").change(function() {
    test = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

    $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", test); 

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `minDate` to 1 day later than the chosen `#startDate` like this:

```
$("#startDate").change(function() {
  var test = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  test.setDate(test.getDate() + 1);
  $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", test); 
}); ​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pPgb2/).